# SNS SDK for NodeJS won't create FIFO topic

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-js

When I create a topic using the sns.createTopic (like the code below) it won't accept the booleans and say 'InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Attributes['FifoTopic'] to be a string', even though the docs say to provide boolean value, and when I provide it with a string of 'true' it still doesn't set the topic type to be FIFO, anyone knows why?

Here's the code:

```
const TOPIC = {
    Name: 'test.fifo',
    Attributes: {
        FifoTopic: true,
        ContentBasedDeduplication: true
    },
    Tags: [{
        Key: 'test-key',
        Value: 'test-value'
    }]
};
sns.createTopic(TOPIC).promise().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Used [aws-sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/) V2
- I sent FifoTopic and ContentBasedDeduplication as strings.

The below code works fine for me

```
const TOPIC = {
    Name: 'test.fifo',
    Attributes: {
        FifoTopic: "true",
        ContentBasedDeduplication: "true"
    },
    Tags: [{
        Key: 'test-key',
        Value: 'test-value'
    }]
};
let sns = new AWS.SNS();
let response3 =await sns.createTopic(TOPIC).promise();
console.log(response3);
```

Note: Make sure your lambda has correct permissions.
[image]

- You will be getting attributes like FifoTopic and ContentBasedDeduplication when performing the getTopicAttributes.

  **let respo = await sns.getTopicAttributes({
  TopicArn:"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXX:test.fifo"}
  ).promise()**;

please find the screenshot
[image]

Comment: When you use getTopicAttributes do you get the "FifoTopic" and "ContentBasedDeduplication" values back in the "Attributes" key? because I don't get them (even though the docs say that they should be returned) that's why I assumed that the topic is not FIFO (I use SNS locally for dev with the localstack docker image therefore I don't have the console to check for the topic type)

Comment: Hi,
It's returning the FIFO attributes when performing the sns.getTopicAttributes. please find the above answer.